# Every continuous open mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ is monotonic

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, monotone-functions, open-map

Consider the image of an open set $(a,b)$ under the open and continuous mapping $f$. We show, $f$ cannot have any extremum in $(a,b)$.

We know, connected sets are mapped to connected sets under a continuous map. Hence, $f[(a,b)]=(c,d)$ is connected (and open). Suppose, at $\xi \in (a,b)$, $f(\xi)=\sup_{(a,b)} f=M$  (or $\inf_{(a,b)}f=m$). [Being a continuous function, $f$ must attain its supremum/infimum.]

Hence, the image of the set $(a,b)$ under $f$ becomes $(c,M]$ or $[m,d)$, which is a contradiction of the fact that $f$ maps open sets to open sets. Therefore, in any open interval, the function cannot attain glb/lub at an interior point. So, we conclude that the inf and sup are at the end points, i.e. $\sup_{[a,b]}f=f(a)$ or $f(b)$.

Hence the theorem.

Is the proof valid? I am aware of the duplicates. I just want this method verified.

Comment: i am going to take down my previous question

Comment: If the question is essentially the same, you just want to change the presentation, it makes more sense to edit the old question, rather than delete and then immediately re-ask.

Comment: Thank you! will keep that in mind.

Comment: Your proof is not correct, first because the extreme value theorem doesn't apply on an open interval, and second because such "global" reasoning doesn't invalidate the possibility of a function whose global extrema on $[a,b]$ are at the endpoints but nevertheless has some local extremum.

Comment: We take a large open interval $(-B,B)$ and the closed interval $[-B, B]$. By the argument, $\sup f = f(B)$ & $\inf f =f(-B)$ (or other way around). We shorten the interval by taking $[-B+ \epsilon, B]$. $f(-B) \leq f(-B+\epsilon)$ [$f(-B)=\inf f$]  And, for your first objection: We first show by taking an open interval (where the extremum value theorem does not necessarily hold), that it is impossible for the function to attain its bounds within it. Now we extend the interval $(a,b)$ to $[a,b]$. Now, extremum value theorem holds and by previous reasoning, extremum lie at the boundary points.

Comment: @Ian Is this the right way to tackle it?